# Yup conditional object validation not working

Tags: javascript, yup

I'm trying to define a Yup validation for an object - if a defined sibling is set to **true**, the field of type **object** should be required, otherwise not

Example:

```
const { object, string, number, date, boolean } = require('yup')

const contactSchema = object({
  isBig: boolean(),
  count: number()
    .when('isBig', {
      is: true, // alternatively: (val) => val == true
      then: number().min(5),
      otherwise: number().min(0),
    }),
 complexOne: object({
    simpleOne: string(),
 })
 .when('isBig', {
     is: true,
     then: object().required(),
     otherwise: object(),
 })
})
```

The object passed into the validation:

```
{
    isBig: true,
    count: -1,
}
```

As you can see, I intentionally don't pass the `complexOne` since I want Yup to display the error. The validation for the **count** works correctly - if the value is less than 0 and the **isBig** is set to **true**, Yup will correctly display an error message `ValidationError: count must be greater than or equal to 5`

Unfortunately, it completely ignores the conditional validation set for the **complexOne** field. Either yup does not support the `when` for object types or I'm doing something incorrectly.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set `strict` option to `true` in order to only validate the object, and skip any coercion or transformation:

```
contactSchema.validate(contact, { strict: true })
.then(obj => {
  console.log(obj)
}, err => {
  console.log(err.message)
})
```

**Demo**:

[image: Edit yup-strict-validation]